# 2checkout: My approved URL's CSS appears broken when using "direct return"

Tags: 2checkout

I've been trying to solve this issue and have had long discussions with 2Checkout support guys, to no avail.

I have a static site. I was using "header redirect" method, but I'm changing to "Direct return" because I want the variables to be sent via POST.

The problem (which seems to be pretty common) is that my Approved URLS's CSS completely breaks when it's fetched internally by 2Checkout.

I followed the steps in http://help.2checkout.com/articles/FAQ/Why-Are-the-Images-Links-on-my-Approved-URL-Broken/?q=why+are+the+images+links&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1 but it still doesn't work. I'm able to see the images (which are coded with relative paths inside the HTML), but I have no CSS in the page when the purchase process ends.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [2Checkout Direct Return method](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/checkout/passback/return-setup) just prints the HTML that was returned by your approved URL while the customer is still at 2Checkout which is why relative paths will not resolve. The `<base>` tag that you are using should work fine in the header as long as the base path is correct and it is added to the header before any CSS/JS files are pulled in. If you have any issues, please contact 2Checkout tech support at techsupport@2co.com.